# How to make multiple CSS background-images fluid responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a fluid responsive website that contains multiple sections that incorporate CSS background images. How would I go about making these images fluid responsive? I am aware of how to do this with a standard  tag but can't see to figure this out for CSS background images. As you can see below the  tags will each contain a background-image in my CSS.

My Site Structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="background-image-one"></section>
    <section id="background-image-two"></section>
    <section id="background-image-three"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add your CSS to the question. It would be more helpful

Comment: you could start by putting content in the sections. a block element with nothing in it has a 0px height by default, so you wouldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) which will scale the images this should work on most mobile devices - not on some older desktop browsers though (the usual suspects). This will not shrink the image though so it might worth looking at something like this http://adaptive-images.com/ which can server images of different sizes to devices with different screen sizes. N.B. not different viewport sizes.

Comment: ah... faster by 1 min. Yes this is the answer. You can set the `background-size` like this `background-size:100% 100%` and it will shrink the image.

Comment: In other words I would apply background-size: 100% 100% to each of the above sections with the id's?